# Deploying NodeJS app on production server - service unavailable during build

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, deployment

I have a nodejs app (written in NestJS) and I used CodePipeline & AWS Elastic Beanstalk to deploy my app on production environment.

Our NodeJS App is an API that will be used by third-party companies all the time.

The issue is that whenever I am deploying new changes to production, there will be a time my API is unavailable due to it is being rebuilt. (eg: npm run build then npm run start:prod)

I would like to ask if you have encountered similar problem and if you have any advices for my case. Thanks a lot!

(I'm thinking of creating a separate dist/ folder for built and copy its content over but I'm not sure if it's feasible...)

EDIT: I found the answers.
It can be done with either Deployment Strategy Blue/Green or just simply to change the Deployment Policy of Elastic Beanstalk to Immutable, etc.

This post has the full answer:
[AWS Elastic Beanstalk goes down for a split second on deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671446/aws-elastic-beanstalk-goes-down-for-a-split-second-on-deploy)

Answer (score 0):

Usually you wouldn't want to build on EB, you would build in a pipeline and push the production-ready assets to EB. That pipeline could be in Jenkins, Circle, CodePipeline, or whatever you want. If that doesn't work for you, then EB has a feature built right in: rolling deployments. That scales your app up for the new deployment, waits until it's healthy, then scales out the old version. [Docs are here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.rolling-version-deploy.html) — there are a few options, but the best one if you're going to be building in prod would be "Rolling with additional batch."

Comment: Thanks! I found out about this just after I posted my question as well :(